# Prime number of divisors, where does one use this?

Tags: number-theory

I recently asked this question [Total number of divisors is a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551454/total-number-of-divisors-is-a-prime).

How useful is this property? What are its applications?

Comment: As you can see from the answers to your first question, there aren't many numbers with this property, and they aren't extremely interesting.

Comment: So it has no applications currently whatsoever?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that. It may be a useful little lemma for some proof. But, it's not that profound of a result.

Comment: Generally, this is a bad way to find number classes have have interesting applications. There are lots of classes of numbers, and very few of them have useful applications.

Comment: You might as well ask a monkey to pick a random assortment of mathematical adjectives until a well-defined property is described and then ask for the potential uses and applications.

Comment: Its just that I was excited when I learned it, I'm not a student of Mathematics...so I thought I could ask an expert's view on this, because I googled it and found nothing closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is as useful as to say that a given number $n$ is of the form $p^{q-1}$ for primes $p$ and $q$. Indeed, $\tau(n)$ is prime if and only if $n=p^{q-1}$. Of course, the arithmetic function $\tau (n)$ is important in number theory. Even more so the function $\sigma(n)$, the sum of all divisors. The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to an elementary statement on $\sigma(n)$, see the paper of Lagarias (2002), "An elementary problem equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis".

Answer (score 0):

I got this helpful answer at *Ask Dr.Math* so I'm posting it.

A number with just two divisors is prime, and primes are useful.  But is it useful to
characterize the numbers with exactly 17 divisors (for example)?  I don't know.

The concept that has applications is that of "multiplicative function".  In number theory, a
function f is called multiplicative if whenever m and n are relatively prime, **f** (**mn**)= **f** (**m**) **f** (**n**).
The function **d** (**n**) that counts the number of divisors of n is one example.

If **f** is multiplicative, **f** is completely determined once you know its values on prime powers.
That's the key thing we need to know to characterize the numbers n for which **d** (**n**) is
prime.  So in my opinion, the importance of this problem is that it helps get you more
familiar with the idea of a multiplicative function.  It's this concept that has the
applications.